# function to create a column with sub areas corresponding to areas in an already existing column

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

[image]

There's a list

```
bareas = ['Hosa road', 'Agara', 'Koramangala 4th block', 'Ali Asker road', 'Singasandra']
```

(its a rather long list so only adding some items here). I want to create a new column named `sub_area` and *label it with the sub-area name to which the residence belongs*.

The [webpage](https://kgis.ksrsac.in)  has the details regarding which *residence* belongs to which *sub-area*.

There are total 8 sub-areas:

`BOMMANAHALLI, DASARAHALLI, MAHADEVAPURA, BYATARAYANAPURA, WEST, EAST, SOUTH, RR_NAGARA`.

I'm a beginner, so please excuse if the problem wasn't clear.

```
i have tried the following code
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd
df2015 = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/the-curious-analyst/Sem2NITDSProject/main/tanker-water-data-2015.csv', usecols = [*range(0,9,1)])
bareas = list(df2015['Area where apartment is situated'].unique())

zone_list = []

for area in bareas:
  url = "https://kgis.ksrsac.in/Bbmpgis/"
  esri-search__form
  data = {'search': area, 'submit': 'Find Address or Place'}
  response = requests.post(url, data=data)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
  zone_element = soup.find('div', class_='lblzn')

  if zone_element:
    zone_list.append(zone_element.text)
  else:
    zone_list.append(None)

print(zone_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests

params = {
    "SingleLine": "Hosa road",
    "location": '{"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100},"x":8646979.114049532,"y":1449843.5729579679}',
    "maxLocations": "6",
    "outFields": "Addr_type,Match_addr,StAddr,City",
    # "outSR": '{"latestWkid":3857,"wkid":102100}',
    "f": "json",
}

url = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates"

bareas = ["Hosa road", "Koramangala 4th block", "Ali Asker road", "Singasandra"]

for a in bareas:
    params["SingleLine"] = a
    data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()

    # print(data)

    print(a)
    print("-" * 80)
    for c in data["candidates"]:
        print(c["address"])
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Hosa road
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hosa Road, Kaikondrahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560035
Hosa Road, Ambalipura, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560102
Hosa Road, Kasavanahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560035
Hosa Road, Kasavanahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560100
Hosa Road, Rayasandra, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560100
Hosa Road, Rayasandra, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560035

Koramangala 4th block
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4th Block, Koramangala, Bengaluru, Karnataka
Koramangala Ring Road, Koramangala, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560095
Koramangala Ring Road, Koramangala, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560034

Ali Asker road
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ali Asker Road, Shivajinagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560001
Ali Asker Road, Vasanth Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka, 560001

Singasandra
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Singasandra, Bengaluru, Karnataka
Singasandra, Anekal Sub-District, Bengaluru, Karnataka
Singasandra, Kanakapura, Ramanagara, Karnataka
Singasandra, Chintamani, Chikkaballapura, Karnataka
Singasandra, Turuvekere, Tumakuru, Karnataka
Singasandra, Ramanagara, Karnataka
```